# Change between two xaml pages when button clicked

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I am creating an application in visual studio 2017. I have two .xaml pages and I want to change between the two when a button is clicked. So far my code is:

```
private void bakingButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CookingMenu cooking = new CookingMenu();
            cooking.show();
        }
```

The page I am on is called BakingMenu.xaml and I want to go to CookingMenu.xaml. However, this gives the error message: `The type or namespace name 'CookingMenu' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Do I need to reference the other file somewhere else in the code or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a reference to where `CookingMenu` is defined; specifically the namespace it is defined in. If you created both `CookingMenu.xaml` and `BakingMenu.xaml` in the same folder in your Visual Studio project, and left thier namespaces as the default generated namespaces, then they will be in the same namespace, and you don't need a reference.

If you created them in different folders, however, or edited their namespaces, then they are in different namespaces, and you need a reference.

Think of it like you are using the first name for your page (class), but the compiler doesn't know which "Joe" you are referring to. You need to use its full name.

You can do this reference in-line (although you need to use it EVERY time you reference the `CookingMenu` type):

```
NameSpace.CookingMenu cooking = new NameSpace.CookingMenu();
```

Where `NameSpace` is replaced by whatever the namespace `CookingMenu` is declared in (which you can see by opening the C# file for `CookingMenu`, and looking near the top... it likely includes several words separated by periods). An example namespace might look like `MyApp.Models.Class`. By default, it wraps around your class definition (so it is the outer-most set of curly braces). Do not include "namespace" in your reference, but simply everything that follows it on that line.

Alternatively, you can put a single namespace reference on the top of your file, and then you don't need to include the namespace in every single reference (within that file):

```
using NameSpace;
```

Then you can use the code you have written as written.

Here is the documentation on the `using` directive: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Both files are stored in the same folder and both have the same namespace. I added the `using namespace;` line at the top but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I am assuming you swapped "namespace" for the actual namespace they are stored in. If so, maybe it is an error in Visual Studio? Try cleaning your project, then building it again (both from the Project menu in Visual Studio. Also, if you see the red error lines under `CookingMenu`, hover over it and click on the little lightbulb icon that appears, and see what it says.